# what does int temp[256 + 128] = {0}; and temp[+str[i]] = 1; mean

Tags: c, gcc, argc, unistd.h

i was googling an exercise that takes the 2 arrays and print the output without character duplication then i found this one which it was more easy to read and modify but the thing is i did not understand the meaning of **int temp[256 + 128] = {0};** and  **temp[+str[i]] = 1;**

here is the full code

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    remove_dup(char *str, char *str2)
{
    int temp[256 + 128] = {0};
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        if (temp[(int)str[i]] == 0)
        {
            temp[+str[i]] = 1;
            write(1, &str[i], 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (str2[i])
    {
        if (temp[+str2[i]]  == 0)
        {
            temp[+str2[i]] = 1;
            write(1, &str2[i], 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc == 3)
        remove_dup(argv[1], argv[2]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The `256 + 128` suggests the code was designed to work with either signed `char` or `unsigned char`, and the `+str[i]` and `+str2[i]` should have been `128+str[i]` and `128+str2[i]`.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
int temp[256 + 128] = {0};
```

Creates an array of `int` of size 256+128 = 384, explicitly initializes the first element to 0, and implicitly initializes the rest to 0.

And this:

```
temp[+str[i]] = 1;
```

Contains an example of the unary `+` operator which is analogous to the unary `-` operator.  This operator effectively does nothing, so this expression is the same as:

```
temp[str[i]] = 1;
```

Which uses `str[i]` as the index into array `temp` and assigns the value 1 to that element.

Comment: i appreciate it , would you please run the code and explain to me how to works cause it's driving me crazy

Comment: @RyadMney That's a separate question, and one that's too broad.

Comment: okay man but i appreciate your explanation <3

Comment: @RyadMney: The source code uses `temp` to record whether a character has been seen or not, by setting `temp[x]` to 1 when the character with value `x` is seen. Whenever the code sees a character that has not been seen previously, it writes it to standard output. It does this first for `str` and then for `str2`. The result is that each character that appears in either `str` or `str2` is written once to standard output, regardless of how many additional times it appears.